# Удаление слов, начинающихся на букву "М"

Tags: python

> Задана строка из стихотворения: «Мой дядя самых честных правил, Когда не в шутку занемог, Он уважать себя заставил И лучше выдумать не мог»
>
> Удалите из строки все слова, начинающиеся на букву «м». Результат вывести на экран в виде строки.

Ищу как это делать на этой странице: [Функции и методы списков](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html). Но не могу понять: 1) Как находить такие слова? 2) Как их удалять (remove???)?

```
st="«Мой дядя самых честных правил,Когда не в шутку занемог,Он уважать себя заставил И лучше выдумать не мог»"
print(st)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где тут список, что имеет смысл искать на той странице?

Comment: Да, это моя вина. Это строка, конечно же.

Comment: Меня тут сбила подсказка к задаче: 

Подсказка: вспомните про модификацию списков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(' '.join(w for w in st.split(' ') if not w.startswith('м')))
```

Comment: Ваш ответ пока для меня выглядит словно кролик, которого вытащили из шляпы :)

Comment: Надеюсь, когда-нибудь я пойму почему это работает.

Comment: Решение не будет удалять слова, начинающиеся на заглавную М. Чтобы и их тоже удаляло, фильтрующее условие нужно дополнить: if not w.lower().startswith('м')

Comment: Плюс именно в том виде, в котором строку привёл автор вопроса, первое слово не будет удалено из-за внутренних кавычек. Но, кажется, это уже косяк автора, строка должна быть без внутренних кавычек.